# Laravel Blade href when clicked keeps same view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I currently have the following clickable href options:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#pricing" aria-controls="pricing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pricing</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#features" aria-controls="features" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Features</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#ideals" aria-controls="ideals" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Ideals</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#paper" aria-controls="paper" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Paper & Specs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When href is clicked it changes the partial view.

[image]

The problem I'm having is when I click through these the partial view changes but it retains the last one.  Meaning it becomes viewable but it stays in the dom.

This is an example of one:

```
<!-- printing pricing -->
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="pricing">
    <!-- @pricing -->
    <div class="product-shortdescript pricingCalculator">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            <div id="reactApp"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Comment: Did you check for errors in your console ?